# powershell - creating dynamic printer script - output and command stucture

Tags: powershell, printing

I am attempting to create a script using powershell that I can use to make a list of:

- network printers a user currently has installed
- printer drivers that are currently installed on the users PC

I have managed to come up with the following script. I am still very new to powershell and I know it isn't the prettiest, but it is working to some degree.

```
$username=[Environment]::UserName
$machinename=[Environment]::MachineName

## Get installed printers and create template command
$printers=get-WmiObject Win32_printer -Property Name | where { $_.Name -like "\\printserver1\*" -or $_.Name -like "\\printserver2\*" }

$printers2=$printers | select-object Name
$printers2 > C:\testdir\"$username"PRINTERS.txt

$printers3=get-content C:\testdir\"$username"PRINTERS.txt | select-string -pattern "\\"


foreach ( $y in $printers3 )
 {
 write-host RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL','PrintUIEntry /dn /n'"'$y
 } 

    ## Get drivers and create template command

$printerdrivers=get-wmiobject -class Win32_PrinterDriver -Property Name
$printerdrivers2=$printerdrivers -split('=') #| select-string 'Name'
$printerdrivers3=$printerdrivers2 | select-string 'HP'

foreach ( $i in $printerdrivers3 )
  {
   $removeprinter=$i -split (',') | select-string 'HP'
   #write-host $removeprinter
   write-host rundll32 printui.dll','PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\$machinename /m $removeprinter'"' /h "x64" /v "Type 3 - User Mode"
  }
```

the above code produces the following output:

```
    RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /dn /n"\\printserver1\ACC_PRINT_HP9040UPS                                                                                                                                                                      

rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine1 /m "HP Universal Printing PS (v5.1)" /h x64 /v Type 3 - User Mode
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine1 /m "HP Universal Printing PS (v5.2)" /h x64 /v Type 3 - User Mode
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine1 /m "HP Designjet T770 24in HPGL2" /h x64 /v Type 3 - User Mode
```

where I am having problems is in two places.

Firstly, is it possible for me to run these commands from within the same script without outputting them to a text file and running them as a batch file? When I attempting to run the template commands I keep getting an error saying that the printer doesn't exist. Unfortunately I can't tell how powershell is actually formulating the command.

Secondly, for the printers installed section, I can't get quotation marks around the printer name for some reason when I do the write-host command. I can get it to show up at the beginning of the printer name "**"\printerserver1\ACC_PRINT_HP9040UPS**" , but not at the end.

I know this code is probably really bad, but I am hoping that I have something here that I can work with. My primary goal was to have something dynamic that I can run against any computer and have it clean up the printers and printer drivers. I will be running it in conjunction with our regular batch files. That is where I will be controlling the 'spooler' service.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

===================== Edit section to contain changes empo suggested!
I just wanted to add as well that the function "Remove-Spaces" is not my work!
I found it on another website and incorporated it into my script. [Original is here](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/02/powershell-remove-spaces/)

```
   $username=[Environment]::UserName
    $machinename=[Environment]::MachineName
    ## this function removes all the blank spaces I had
    Function Remove-Spaces {
      param($target)

      begin {
        filter Do-RemoveSpaces { $_ -replace "\s *", "" }
      }

      process { if($_) { $_ | Do-RemoveSpaces } }

      end { if($target) {$target | Do-RemoveSpaces} }
    }


    $printers=get-WmiObject Win32_printer -Property Name | where { $_.Name -like "\\printerserver1\*" -or $_.Name -like "\\printerserver2\*" }
    $printers2=$printers | select-object Name | select-string -pattern "\\"
    $printers2 > C:\testdir\"$username"PRINTERS.txt
    $printers3=get-content C:\testdir\"$username"PRINTERS.txt | select-string -pattern "\\"

    foreach ( $y in Remove-Spaces $printers3 )
     {
      write-output "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /dn /n`"$y`"" | out-file *blah*
     }

    $printerdrivers=get-wmiobject -class Win32_PrinterDriver -Property Name
    $printerdrivers2=$printerdrivers -split('=') #| select-string 'Name'
    $printerdrivers3=$printerdrivers2 | select-string 'HP'

    foreach ( $i in $printerdrivers3 )
      {
       $removeprinter=$i -split (',') | select-string 'HP'
       #write-host $removeprinter
       write-output "rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\$machinename /m $removeprinter`"` /h x64 /v `"Type 3 - User Mode`"" | out-file *blah*
      }
```

The output now looks like this:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /dn /n"\\printerserver1\ACC_PRINT_HP9040UPS"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine1 /m "HP Universal Printing PS (v5.1)" /h x64 /v Type 3 - User Mode
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine1 /m "HP Universal Printing PS (v5.2)" /h x64 /v Type 3 - User Mode
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dd /c\\machine1 /m "HP Designjet T770 24in HPGL2" /h x64 /v Type 3 - User Mode
```

I believe that this will work... hopefully anyway. I am going to do some testing and I will report back and make sure to mark this as answered!

Scratch the out-file fix.. it doesn't work :(
still need to do additional testing

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to help you just on the first section of your script, about printers.

First, why are you redirecting printers into a text files?

```
## Get installed printers and create template command
$printers=get-WmiObject Win32_printer -Property Name | where { $_.Name -like "\\printserver1\*" -or $_.Name -like "\\printserver2\*" }
```

with this you should have already all the printers.
Second, escape double quotes using backticks.
Third, try to use `write-output`instead of `write-host`.

```
foreach ( $printer in $printers )
 {
   write-output "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /dn /n `"$printer.name`""
 }
```

If it does not work yet, append to the pipeline the `invoke-expression` with `out-null`:

```
foreach ( $printer in $printers )
 {
   write-output "RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /dn /n `"$printer.name`"" | invoke-expression | out-null
 }
```

You can also try with `invoke-item`.

Comment: Thank you empo,

Your first suggestion with the backticks worked perfectly and actually uncovered another problem in my script (among other things).

The reason I output to a text file is because if I attempt to process $printer2 from within the script I get a weird output: 
"@{Name=\\printerserver1\ACC_PRINT_HP9040UPS}"

I have tried processing this but I can't seem to get the printer name out of what appears to be an array, it will only output in this format. So when I plug it into my template command, the command immediately fails.

Comment: what you additionally uncovered for me was that my out command in $printers2 actually contained a whole bunch of additional blank spaces that I didn't need. I manged to find a small function to replace the blank spaces so that the command outputs correctly. I'm entirely sure how to post the code again, but I think I have to edit my original post above. I will do so with the edits you provided me.

Comment: Glad that you find my answer helpful. I've edited the code sections so that you should be able to get rid of $printer2 and $printer3 variables. Unfortunately, I can't test code now so consider my answer as guessing. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your help empo. It looks like this is going to work out perfectly for my requirements! Thank you again for your help!